# Hiding elements with ng-hide and radios?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a radio:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col15">
    <input type="radio" id="client_yes" name="client" ng-model="entry.client" ng-required="true" value="yes"><label for="client_yes">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col15">
    <input type="radio" id="client_no" name="client" ng-model="entry.client" ng-required="true" value="no"><label for="client_no">No</label>
  </div>

</div>
```

When client_yes is selected I want some questions on the form to be hidden using ng-hide.

I've check out the example in the docs:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHide

This uses a tick box to hide:

```
ng-hide="checked"
```

Checked is the name of the ng-model of the tick box, I'm just not sure how to work it with radios as they both have the same model name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ng-hide directive on the questions div like this:

```
ng-hide="entry.client=='yes'"
```

See the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/o2dXzq3lTGy4iBPxS6MT?p=preview

This is the HTML code:

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col15">
        <input type="radio" id="client_yes" name="client" ng-model="entry.client" ng-required="true" value="yes" />
        <label for="client_yes">Yes</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col15">
        <input type="radio" id="client_no" name="client" ng-model="entry.client" ng-required="true" value="no" />
        <label for="client_no">No</label>
      </div>

      <div class="col15" ng-hide="entry.client=='yes'">
      question to hide
      </div>
      <div class="col15">
      question NOT to hide
      </div>
      <div class="col15" ng-hide="entry.client=='yes'">
      question to hide
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to hide questions to start with, as at the start, no radio button is checked.

Comment: A simple way would be to replace ng-hide with ng-show, e.g.: `ng-show="entry.client=='no'"`

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput.radio), you can use the `value` attribute to set each radio button to a different value on selection:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col15">
    <input type="radio" id="client_yes" name="client" value="yes" ng-model="entry.client" ng-required="true"><label for="client_yes">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col15">
    <input type="radio" id="client_no" name="client" value="no" ng-model="entry.client" ng-required="true"><label for="client_no">No</label>
  </div>
```

Then you could hide based on the value:

```
ng-hide="entry.client == 'yes'"
```